# Rewriting Images to S3

Tags: mod-rewrite, amazon-s3

I'm looking for a way to rewrite images to be served from amazon S3

we cannot rewrite them based folder because we have following patter

```
/product/name -> for product url
/product/name.jpg -> product image
/store/name -> store url
```

/store/name.jpg -> store image

what would be the best way to rewrite images

```
/product/name.jpg -> http://amazonbucket/product/name.jpg
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things you can do is to assign a CNAME to your Amazon S3 domain. In this case you will have to name your bucket something like images.yourdomain.com and you will be able to serve your images from http://images.yourdomain.com/product/name.jpg